# How to Send Data to KendoWindow Close Event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I'm trying to open a Kendo UI kendoWindow from within an MVC View. I also use a Partial View as the content of the kendoWindow. Moreover, I use the Kendo UI MVVM pattern to bind my elements.

First let me to show you my main View and my pop-up Partial View (kendoWindow).

The important part of my main View (Parent) is as follows:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Main View";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/ViewModel/main.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/InitView/main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel;

    $(function () {
        viewModel = initVm({
            GetPartialContent_Url: '@Url.Action("GetPartialContent")'
        });

        initView(viewModel);
        kendo.bind($("#container"), viewModel);
        viewModel.Onread();
    });
</script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="Window-box"></div>
    // Some other elements like the button which opens the kendoWindow are defined here.
</div>
```

My initVm is as follows:

```
function initVm(arg) {
    var vm = kendo.observable({
        onOpenKendoWindow: function () {
            $("#Window-box").kendoWindow({
                iframe: true,
                content: arg.GetPartialContent_Url,
                title: 'Some Title',
                width: 500,
                height: 'auto',
                close: function (e) {
                    //Is it possible to get some data from kendoWindow (Partial View) here?
                }
            });

            var dialog = $("#Window-box").data("kendoWindow");
            dialog.maximize();
        }
    });

    return vm;
}
```

Until now, I showed you the important parts of my main View. Now I want to show you the important parts of my kendoWindow (Partial View).

My Partial View which is used as the content of the kendoWindow is as follows:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PartialLayout.cshtml";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/ViewModel/partial.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/InitView/partial.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var partialVM;

    $(function () {
        partialVM = initPartialVm({
            GetTransactions_Url: '@Url.Action("GetTransactions", "Account")'
        });

        initPartialView(partialVM);
        kendo.bind($("#container"), partialVM);
    });
</script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="gridTransactions"></div>
</div>
```

And my initPartialVm is as follows:

```
function initPartialVm(arg) {
    var vm = kendo.observable({
        onSelectTransaction: function () {
            // KendoWindow should be closed here and passing some data from here to main View (close event of kendowWindow);
        }
    });

    return vm;
}
```

**Note:** The 'gridTransactions' is a Kendo UI GridView (inside of kendoWindow - Partial View). Each rows of this grid has a select button and the 'onSelectTransaction' function is fired when each of these select buttons is clicked.

And finally, the main question is that, how can I close the kendowWindow by clicking each select button of the GridView and pass some data to the close event of the kendowWindow?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. I found it much easier and a bit cleaner to wrap all the dialog functionality up into a dialog controller and extend it a bit in javascript.

Once the .js part is done it makes for a cleaner use. If you don't prefer to do this then look for the `findDialog` function below (it **shows how get a handle to a dialog and call the close method on it**).

As far as sending data on close, It would be easy to add a callback in the dialog to be called when the dialog is closed, supplied on invocation, then add a property in the widget to set the custom data to pass through in the dialogs close() back to the consumers event handler.

Also, please note I am no javascript expert, it took me longer than I would like to admit to work the bugs out of this but it has held up solidly for about 6 years. Feel free to offer suggestions.

**In Bundle Config:**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myCustom").Include(
            ...
             "~/Scripts/MyCustom/MyCustomDialogs.js",
            ...
 ));
```

**Where you register scripts:**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MyCustom")
```

**In your index view or parent view :**

```
<div id="_applicationDialogs"></div>  
<div id="_mainAppContentLoadsHere"></div> 

var _mainDialogController;

$(document).ready(function () {
     ...
    _mainDialogController = $("#_applicationDialogs").kendoMyCustomDialogController().data("kendoMyCustomDialogController");
     ...
}
```

**Where you want to invoke the dialog: SomePartial**

```
function lnkDetailsOnClick(someID) {
    _mainDialogController.createDialog({
        dialogId: "frmUserDetail_" + someID,
        modal: false,
        title:"Daily Details",
        pin: true,
        height: 575,           
        width: 1025,
        actions: ["Refresh", "Maximize", "Minimize", "Pin", "Close"],
        url: '@Url.Action("SomePartialView", "SomeController")',
        data:{
            someID: someID,
            dialogName:'frmUserDetail_'+ someID //NOTE : This will come back in the invoked partial as Model.DialogName so it can be dismissed with ease.
        }
    });
```

}

**Dismissing the Dialog Inside of SomePartial :**

```
@model MyModelThatHasTheDialogHandle

function btnClose_Click() {
    var dialog = _mainDialogController.findDialog('@Model.DialogName');
    dialog.close();
}
```

**Now for the long .js file :**

```
(function ($) {
    var kendo = window.kendo,
    ui = kendo.ui,
    Widget = ui.Widget;

    var MyCustomDialogController = Widget.extend({

        init: function (element, options) {
            var that = this;
            Widget.fn.init.call(this, element, options);
            that._create();
        },

        onResize: function () { },

        options: {
            modal: true,
            dialogId: "dlgController1",
            url: "",
            data: null,
            pin: false,
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            actions:["Close"],
            title: "Information",
            disableMaximize:false,
            name: "MyCustomDialogController",
            autosize: false,
            onDialogClosed: null,
            hideOnClose: false
        },
        _create: function () {
            var that = this;            

        },
        createDialog: function (options) {
            var that = this;
            var wrapperName = options.dialogId + "_wrapper";
            that.element.append("<div id='" + wrapperName + "'></div>");
            var wrapperElement = that.element.find("#" + wrapperName);
            wrapperElement.kendo_MyCustomDialog(options);
        },
        findDialog: function (dialogId) {
            that = this;
            var wrapperName = dialogId+"_wrapper";
            var dialog = $("#" + wrapperName);
            //var dialog = wrapper.find("#" + dialogId);
            return dialog.data("kendo_MyCustomDialog");
        },
        forceCloseAllDialogs: function ()
        {
            that = this;
            $('.MyCustom-window').each(function () {
                $(this).data("kendoWindow").close();                
            });
        },
        isModalWindowActive: function ()
        {
            that = this;

            return $('.MyCustom-window-modal').length > 0;
        },
        currentModalWindow: function () {
            that = this;           
            return that.findDialog($('.MyCustom-window-modal')[0].id);
        }

    });
    ui.plugin(MyCustomDialogController);
})(jQuery);


(function ($) {

    var kendo = window.kendo,
    ui = kendo.ui,
    Widget = ui.Widget;

    var _MyCustomDialog = Widget.extend({

        init: function (element, options) {
            var that = this;
            Widget.fn.init.call(this, element, options);
            that._create();
        },

        onResize: function () { },

        options: {
            modal: true,
            dialogId: "frmMain",
            url: "",
            data: null,
            pin: false,
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            actions: ["Close"],
            title: "Information",
            name: "_MyCustomDialog",
            disableMaximize:false,
            autosize: false,
            onDialogClosed: null,
            hideOnClose:false
        },


        _create: function () {
            var that = this;
            that.isModalWindowActive = true;
            that.modifiedData = false;
            that.frmElement = $("#" + that.options.dialogId).data("kendoWindow");
            if (that.frmElement == null) {

                var template ;
                if(that.options.modal)
                    template = kendo.template(that._templates.divModalFormWrapper);
                else
                    template = kendo.template(that._templates.divFormWrapper);
                that.wrapper = $(template(that.options));
                that.element.append(that.wrapper);

                if (that.options.autosize)
                {
                    that.options.height =null;
                    that.options.width = null;
                }



                that.frmElement = that.wrapper.kendoWindow({

                    title: "Loading...",
                    modal: that.options.modal,
                    visible: that.options.autosize,
                    draggable: true,
                    resizeable:!that.options.disableMaximize,
                    width: that.options.width,
                    height: that.options.height,
                    resizeable: true,
                    pinned:that.options.pin,

                    resize: function () {
                        that.onResize();
                    },
                    content: {
                        url: that.options.url,
                        data: that.options.data,
                        type: "POST",
                        datatype: "json",
                        traditional: true
                    },
                    refresh: function () {
                        that.frmElement.title(that.options.title);
                        if (that.options.autosize) {

                            that.frmElement.center();
                        }
                    },

                    actions: that.options.actions,
                    close: function (e) {
                        that.IsModalWindowActive = false;
                        if (that.options.hideOnClose == false) {
                            if (that.frmElement != null)
                                that.frmElement.destroy();
                            this.destroy();
                            that.wrapper.remove("#" + that.options.dialogId);
                            that.wrapper.empty();

                        }
                        if (that.options.onDialogClosed) {
                            that.options.onDialogClosed(that.modifiedData);
                        }                    
                    }
                }).data("kendoWindow");
            } 
            if (that.options.autosize)
                that.frmElement.center().open();
            else if (that.options.hideOnClose == true)
                that.frmElement.open();
            else
                that.frmElement.center().open();
            if (that.options.pin)
                that.frmElement.pin();

        },
        setModifiedFlag:function(modified)
        {
            var that = this;
            that.modifiedData = modified;
        },
        close: function () {
            var that = this;
            that.frmElement.close();
        },
        show: function () {
            var that = this;
            that.wrapper.show();
            that.frmElement.open();
        },
        setTitle: function (title) {
            var that = this;
            that.frmElement.title(title);
        },
        height: function () {
            var that = this;
            var wtfHeight = that.frmElement.options.height;
            if (isNaN(wtfHeight)) {
                if (wtfHeight.indexOf("px") >= 0)
                    wtfHeight = wtfHeight.replace("px", "");
            }
            return wtfHeight;
        },
        _templates: {
            divModalFormWrapper: "<div id='#=dialogId#' class='MyCustom-window MyCustom-window-modal'></div>",
            divFormWrapper: "<div id='#=dialogId#' class='MyCustom-window'></div>"
        }
    });

    // add the widget to the ui namespace so it's available
    ui.plugin(_MyCustomDialog);



})(jQuery);
```